# Unexpected value 'TransportData' declared by the module 'CoreModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation. in nagular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i create a service in `CoreModule` in angular 8 :

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})

export class TransportData {

    private stringData: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    data$ = this.stringData.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    setStringValue(value: string): void {
        this.stringData.next(value);
    }

}
```

and this is `core.module :`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TransportData],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [TransportData],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_CONFIG,
      useValue: AppConfig
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true
    }
  ],
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

now i need to use that in other component :

`registerComponent` and `activetionComponent` .

in `activation.module` i use this :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ActivetionCodeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ActivationCodeRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports:[ActivetionCodeComponent]
})
export class ActivationCodeModule { }
```

and this in `activetioncomponent:`

```
   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder , private activetionCodeService:ActivetionCodeService , private transpostData: TransportData) { 
    this.intialForm();
  }
```

ti show me this error :

> Unexpected value 'TransportData' declared by the module 'CoreModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})
```

you do not need to add it to CoreModule. The service will be available in the Application for use.

> By default, this decorator has a `providedIn` property, which creates a provider for the service. In this case, `providedIn: 'root'` specifies that Angular should provide the service in the root injector.

However if you choose to not provide it in root, You can add it to `providers` of the `CoreModule`.

You can change `TransportData` to use:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: CoreModule,
})
```

and use the same inside `Coremodule`:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [TransportData],
})
```

Check the official guide for [more details on Injectables and providers.](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules)

Comment: it show me this error : `Cannot access 'CoreModule' before initialization`

Comment: Does your AppModule use CoreModule? With `NgModule`, the way to do it now I think is to create a `CoreModule` with your service class in it, and list the service in the module's `providers`. Then you import the core module in your **main app module** which will provide the one instance to any children requesting that class in their constructors

Comment: i dot his but show me this error : `Cannot access 'CoreModule' before initialization`

Comment: If it's not possible to specify in the service which module should provide it, you can also declare a provider for the service within the CoreModule:`providers: [TransportData],` See this link for a live eaxample: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/ngmodules/stackblitz.html